# CentOS with Systemd on Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, centos, continuous-integration, ansible

I am actually working on automated testing of my playbooks with Gitlab-CI, Ubuntu is working very well and getting no issues.

The Problem actually I have is with CentOS and Systemd, first of all the Playbook ( installing Postgres 9.5 inside CentOS7):

```
- name: Ensure PostgreSQL is running
  service:
    name: postgresql-9.5
    state: restarted
  ignore_errors: true   
  when:
    - ansible_os_family == 'RedHat'
```

so, and this is what I get if i want to start postgres inside the container:

```
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted\nFailed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted\nFailed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted\nFailed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted\nFailed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted\n
```

I already had to run the Container in privileged mode, with c-groups and anything else. Already tried differend Docker Containers but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

When using docker, i think it would be better just use `postgres` to start the server.
Command like

```
postgres -D /opt/postgresql/data/ > /var/log/postgresql/pg_server.log 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use docker, you don't have a fully functional systemd.

You can use the solution suggested by @KJocker to make a postgresql functional container. Or instead you can configure systemd to work inside the container here is a document [check](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/ContainerInterface/)

Comment: After I had started  my docker-systemctl-replacement script I am so lucky that I don't have to go through the hassle of bringing up a systemd daemon anymore ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing when using Ansible on a Docker container.... and I have written a [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) for that. It works for PostgreSQL - no need to change the Ansible script, it can stay that way for a deployment on a real machine.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the conf of your gitlab runner instance `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`

From :

```
[runners.docker]
    privileged = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
```

To :

```
[runners.docker]
    privileged = true
    volumes = ["/sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro", "/cache"]
```

Add :

```
[runners.docker.tmpfs]
    "/run" = "rw"
    "/tmp" = "rw"
[runners.docker.services_tmpfs]
    "/run" = "rw"
    "/tmp" = "rw"
```

Restart gitlab-runner.

On your docker image, edit getty tty1 service to permit autologin of user root after systemd boot up

```
sed -e 's|/sbin/agetty |/sbin/agetty -a root |g' -i /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty\@tty1.service
```

Use that docker image in image name section of `.gitlab-ci.yml` and add the following to start systemd. Do not edit entrypoint

```
  script: 
    - /lib/systemd/systemd --system --log-target=kmsg &
    - sleep 5
    - systemctl start postgresql-9.5
```